# How to pass name of variable in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I want to pass name of variable as sample

```
public string 06:00-07:00 {get; set}
public string 07:00-08:00 {get; set}
```

But it get error `Invalid token '06' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

Comment: what exactly you want. you can not give name of variable like this. do you want to assign this value to the variable ?

Comment: It's incorrect C# code. property name can not start with number and contain `:`, `-`

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Why_ do you want to name the property that way?

Comment: sometime, i want to by pass parameter with same range of hour.

Comment: Why not call it `From6amTo7am`?

Comment: expanding on @mjwills suggestion you could create a enum which has known ranges

Answer (score 3):

It's incorrect C# code.

Following are some of basic rules to declare a variable name.

- The name can contain letters, digits, and the underscore character
  (_).
- The first character of the name must be a letter. The underscore is
  also a legal first character, but its use is not recommended at the
  beginning of a name. An underscore is often used with special
  commands, and it's sometimes hard to read.
- Case matters (that is, upper- and lowercase letters). C# is
  case-sensitive; thus, the names count and Count refer to two
  different variables.
- C# keywords can't be used as variable names. Recall that a keyword is
  a word that is part of the C# language. (A complete list of the C#
  keywords can be found in Appendix B, "C# Keywords.")

Check [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24472) for more details

**You can not bypass this. You have to follow syntax.**

One of the possible solution is

Rename your variables to

```
public string From0600To0700 {get; set;}
public string From0700To0800 {get; set;}
```

OR

```
public string From_0600_0700 {get; set;}
public string From_0700_0800 {get; set;}
```

You can choose any relevant names within the syntax guidelines. Follow the above samples.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- `:` is a special character which denotes a base class/interface for OOP inheritance, so you can't use this in a variable name.
- As per the C# 4 specification, you can't start the name of a class or variable with a number.

If you can, try to give these variables a more descriptive name, it'll help when you (or someone else completely new to the program) goes to maintain it in six months when the business case hypothetically changes and `06:00-07:00` and `07:00-08:00` aren't relevant anymore.